# Pass data to sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to pass props into sibling components like in the given image. I cant explain it in words because it seems too hard to understand(at least for me).

[image]

I have an App(Class component), with the given state variables inside of it. I use the state to generate an object which contains information like a calendar(dates, weeks, years). The buttons appearance are generated by this script.

The **Time table** component takes some props(based on which button is pressed), and those are used to collect data from Firestore Database.

I know React has a one-way data flow, from the top to the bottom, this is why I can't figure this out. I don't want to use Redux, if possible.

Q1: How can I tell the **Time table** component which button was pressed and what date it contains?

Q2: Do I really need to use Redux in these situations?

*Edit

[Here is the draw.io chart I posted above if it helps anyone.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ewEE-55NwlCrz_IAK1Py6dBHbc1ZFCw8/view)

Comment: You can use `context` if don't wanna use redux.

Comment: You can only pass props down, your options are [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), state management (redux) or react context.

Comment: Which one is better? Context or Redux?

Comment: depends on your use if states are too many then use redux

Comment: @Bogdan-DanielMihalcea There is no better, if your requirements are very complex and require lots of logic then redux is the way to go as it's easier to maintain and debug complex requirements. Context is easier to write initially but harder to manage if requirements get more complex (more components get involved in needing to get the data and updating the data that all have different rules on when to update and how to get their data).

Comment: I'll go with Redux than, I never used it before and I'll have to learn it.

Comment: @Bogdan-DanielMihalcea It can be hard to self teach redux and takes a while to understand how and why to use it. If you know what CQRS (event sourcing) is (basic understanding) then you'll know what the advantages are of the redux pattern. Middleware and reducer(s) are the command and selectors are the query (I suggest using reselect). The event sourcing is redux dev tools where you have an overview of what happened (actions) and what changes they made (state). You can even replay the actions (can break if there are time or order specific side effects)

Comment: Geee! I will try to read what you mentioned!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exchange props between sibling components wrapped within common parent, you may [lift](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) source component state up to the common parent's state then pass it down to another (sink) component.

If you need your source component's state to be globally accessible (e.g. to multiple non-adjacent components scattered across your app), you may want to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or some state management tool, like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).

Live-demo of the first approach (at its very simplest) you may find as follows:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const Source = ({onButtonClick}) => (
  <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Hit me</button>
)

const Sink = ({status}) => (
  <div>{status}</div>
)

const Parent = () => {
  const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('off'),
        handleButtonHit = () => 
          setButtonStatus(buttonStatus == 'off' ? 'on' : 'off')
  return (
    <div>
      <Source onButtonClick={handleButtonHit} />
      <Sink status={buttonStatus} />
    </div>
  )
}

render (
  <Parent />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```